# why the error is given while reading the text file in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

The path given to the text file is correct still I am getting error " Input path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/cmpil/Downloads/hunger_games.txt". Why is it happening

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object WordCountDataSet {
  case class Book(value:String)

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("WordCount")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    //Another way of doing it
    val bookRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile("C:/Users/cmpil/Downloads/hunger_games.txt")
    val wordsRDD = bookRDD.flatMap(x => x.split("\\W+"))
    val wordsDS = wordsRDD.toDS()

    val lowercaseWordsDS = wordsDS.select(lower($"value").alias("word"))
    val wordCountsDS = lowercaseWordsDS.groupBy("word").count()
    val wordCountsSortedDS = wordCountsDS.sort("count")
    wordCountsSortedDS.show(wordCountsSortedDS.count().toInt)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on windows you have to use '\\' in place of '/'

try using `"C:\\Users\\cmpil\\Downloads\\hunger_games.txt"`